# Randomly Sample Dataframe with Boolean Conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains 8 columns and 10,000 rows. I would like to randomly sample 3 rows for all combinations of the "1" and "2" columns where the values are `TRUE` (e.g 1a with 2a)

[image]

My initial attempt is as such:

`df[sample(nrow(df[df$1a == TRUE & df$2a == TRUE,]), 3), ]`

Which gives the output.

```
      1a    1b    1c    1d    2a    2b    2c    2d
1136 FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
1021  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
589  FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

It's selecting rows which are FALSE for 1a and 2a. What am I doing wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: Not that clear to me. Maybe try `df[sample(which(df$1a == TRUE & df$2a == TRUE), 3), ]`.

Comment: This worked, thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code

```
df[df$1a == TRUE & df$2a == TRUE,]
```

should return 0 rows because there are no such cases.

If your data frame has more than those 10 lines try to use TRUE as character:

```
df[sample(nrow(df[df$1a == "TRUE" & df$2a == "TRUE",]), 3), ]
```

Comment: Using "TRUE" worked, it's always the little things, thanks!